# Converting from YUY2 to RGB24 from V4L2 API

Tags: c, image, v4l2

I am trying to use the V4L2 API to capture images and put the images into an opencv Mat. The problem is my webcam only captures in YUYV (YUY2) So I need to convert to RGB24 first. Here is the complete V4L2 [code](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html) that I am using.

I was able to get objects in the picture to be recognizable, but it is all pink and green, and it is stretched horizontally and distorted. I have tried many different conversion formulas and I have had the same basic pink/green distorted image. The formula used for this picture is from http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/yuv/. I am using the shotwell photo viewer on linux to view the .raw image. I couldn't get gimp to open it. I am not that knowledgable with how to save image formats, but I am assuming there has to be some kind of header but the shotwell photo viewer seemed to work. Could this possibly be reason for the incorrect image?

I am not sure if V4l2 is returning a signed or unsigned byte image which is pointed to by p. But if this were the problem woudln't my image would just be off-color? But it seems the geometry is distorted too. I believe I took care of the casting to and from floating point properly.

Could someone help me understand

1. how to find out the underlying type contained in the *void p variable
2. the proper formula for converting from YUYV to RGB24 including explanations of which types to use
3. could saving the image with no format (headers) and viewing with Shotwell be the problem?
4. is there an easy way to save an RGB24 image properly.
5. general debugging tips

Thanks

```
static unsigned char   *bgr_image;

static void process_image(void *p, int size)
{
    frame_number++;
    char filename[15];
    sprintf(filename, "frame-%d.raw", frame_number);
    FILE *fp=fopen(filename,"wb");

    int i;
    float y1, y2, u, v;
    char * bgr_p = bgr_image;
    unsigned char * p_tmp = (unsigned char *) p;

    for (i=0; i < size; i+=4) {

      y1 = p_tmp[i];
      u = p_tmp[i+1];
      y2 = p_tmp[i+2];
      v = p_tmp[i+3];

      bgr_p[0] = (y1 + 1.371*(u - 128.0));
      bgr_p[1] = (y1 - 0.698*(u - 128.0) - 0.336*(v - 128.0));
      bgr_p[2] = (y1 + 1.732*(v - 128.0));
      bgr_p[3] = (y2 + 1.371*(v - 128.0));
      bgr_p[4] = (y2 - 0.698*(v - 128.0) - 0.336*(u - 128.0));
      bgr_p[5] = (y2 + 1.732*(u - 128.0));

      bgr_p+=6;
    }

    fwrite(bgr_image, size, 1, fp);                                       
    fflush(fp);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you must understand with what type of YUV422 you are working.

```
PIX_FMT_YUYV422,   ///< packed YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, Y0 Cb Y1 Cr
PIX_FMT_UYVY422,   ///< packed YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, Cb Y0 Cr Y1
```

Try replacing y1, u, y2, and v accordingly, but you maybe be not dealing with YUV422 at all, the picture could be a planar, instead of a packed format you are expecting?

I think its better for you to download IrfanViewer, which has a raw yuv file open functionality and try picking the correct values to have a correctly decoded image to find what type of data you are using.

Comment: According to the documentation on linuxtv.org its supposed to be Y Cb Y Cr. Thanks ll take a look at Irfanvirwer. What do you mean by planar?

Comment: @user1505520 there are 2 types of YUV - packed format (which you are referring) and planars - where Y,U,V are put like slices, one after another - the picture is probably the YUV420 planar IMHO

Comment: I tried Irfanview. I tried all the selections for openging a raw file at 640x480. I was able to get the best picture using 24 bits per pixel but the aspect ratio was off and it was still line-y. I tried 16 bits per pixel and aspect ratio was correct but the picture was terrible. I could not find any option in Irfanviewer for 4:2:2 packing, which is what it is supposedly. I'm gonna try yuvplayer next.

Comment: Interesting. I tried using yuvplayer to open it and got the perfect image openging it with yuy2 format. There were seperate options for yuv422 and yuy2. According to fourcc.org these formats are the same, but yuv422 did not work.

Comment: The options in yuvplayer gave me a dropdown containing: UYVY, Y, YUV420, YUV422, YUV444, and YUY2. YUY2 is the only one that worked.

Comment: @user1505520 so its ///< packed YUV 4:2:2, 16bpp, Cb Y0 Cr Y1 as in my answer

Comment: I just tried assigning the value of u to all rgb values into both pixels in te for loop in hope of creating a correct black and white image. However the image is still distorted in an identical way as the image above. This means it is not 24 bpp right?

Comment: @user1505520 what happens if you flip y1->u y2->v ? O try y1->v y2->u

Comment: Both changes produce a brighter picture but same geometry distortion as above. ie te double vision effect

Answer (score 1):

do not try to re-invent the wheel. lots of people have written colorspace-converters and chances are high that your implementation (even if it works) is not the "optimal" one (e.g. being slower than necessary).

the canonical way to deal with V4L2 devices of *any* colourspace is to use the [libv4l](http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/libv4l.html)-library, which will transparently convert the cameras native colorspace to once of `BGR24`, `RGB24` and `YUV420` (if you desire that, which i think is true).

as for saving the image, again use what is already there. personally, i would use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to save a frame in a "proper" format that can be read by any imageviewer (png or tiff, if quality matters)

Comment: When I use the command "v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext" it says the device can only stream mpeg and yuyv. So I would call ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_S_FMT, &fmt) with V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB ?

Comment: `v4l2-ctl` will only report the native formats. in any case you should use the `v4l2_ioctl` wrappers rather than the native `ioctl`-cmd.